# Combining functions to create a mathematical model

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to apply a new concept that I learned to a real life application.

You work forty hours/week at a store. You receive $\$220$ as a weekly salary, plus a 3% commission on sales over $\$5000$. Create a function to calculate the total amount you would get paid.

So the first part seems fairly simple and I think I got it down. This is the function I created:

let $P =$ pay
let $s =$ sales

$${ P(s)=\{  }_{ 220+.03s\quad if\quad s>5000 }^{ 220\quad if\quad s<5000 }$$

Now the next part is to create a function to determine the amount of sales you'll have over 5000. This makes no sense to me whatsoever. Is this possible, and if yes how would I go about creating one? No direct answer please. I'd rather get a hint/explanation so that I could do it by myself and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very tiny nitpick with your function.  It's not defined at $s=5000.$  This can be fixed by changing either the < or the > to $\leq$ or $\geq.$

The second question may not be clear, but one way to look at it is this:  Given you were paid $P$ one week, how much did your sales $s$ exceed $\$5000$ that week?

You've written $P$ as a function of $s$.  The second part, if what I've stated above is the correct interpretation, involves writing $s$ as a function of $P$, or $s(P)$.

Attack it the same way:

- What would the excess amount have been if you were paid $\$220$?
- If you were paid some amount, $P'$, over $\$220$, how much extra would you have had to sell to make that extra amount?

Comment: the excess amount would be $P-220$. However, I still don't understand how I can use this new number to figure out how many sales I made. Because each sale isn't a constant number. It can be anywhere from $(5000,infinity)$. So I can't just divide the money made in sales by $5000$ to get the amount of sales... if that makes sense

Comment: Well, if you made $\$220$ then your sales were less than $\$5000$ (you got no commission).  So the excess sales is zero.  But if you got paid more than $\$220$ then the amount over is your commission on the sales over $\$5000$.  If your pay was $\$280$, the excess pay is $\$60$, and this is 3 percent of $\$2000$.  Does this help?